# Count number of triples whose product is x

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

Given an array of integers and an integer *x*, I need to find the number of unordered triples in the array whose product is *x*. I have a brute-force O(*n*<sup>3</sup>) solution:

```
int solve(int a[], int n, int x) {
    int ans = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; ++j)
            for (int k = j+1; k < n; ++k)
                if(a[i]*a[j]*a[k] == x)
                    ans++;
    return ans;
}
```

Is there a faster way to do this, say in O(*n* log *n*) time?

Comment: Give us an example. For `nlog(n)`, sort and do a binary search maybe.

Comment: Once numbers are sorted, can be done in linear time.

Comment: To improve on O(n^3), some assumptions are needed.  Posting your brute force O(n^3) solution and sample data sets and expected outputs would add clarity to many of those assumptions.  As is the question is broad.

Comment: I agree, posting your naive solution would add clarity. Specifically, it is not clear why the naive approach takes O(n^3). Looking at the product of every input pair should be O(n^2), right?

Comment: Can numbers be negative ?

Comment: No numbers are positive.  @Jarod42, can u elaborate ur approach?

Comment: @SaiBot: I think OP want triplets, not pairs.

Comment: once sorted, use 3 iterators, one from begin, one from end. and the last from begin + 1. as long as product is bigger than target, end iterator has to be decrease. if it is less, increase mid one. once mid == end, reiterate with `begin+1`, `begin+2`, `end` -> complexity `O(n²)`.

Comment: @Jarod42, I want O(nlog(n)) approach. This is two pointer approach. I was aware of that.

Comment: @RaghavJames it is unlikely that an `O(n log n)` approach exists.

Comment: How big can n be?

Comment: You can make it O(n^2) .

Comment: n is equal to 100000, and hence O(n^2) and higher won't work!

Comment: In your current implementation, if `x = 27` and `a[0] = 3` you won't find the fact that `a[0] * a[0] * a[0] == x`. Is that not a wanted solution? Also since you use `j=i+1` and `k=j+1`, you don't have `O(n³)`. It's less...

Comment: @RaghavJames link to original problem?

Comment: please read the help on what kinds of questions are appropriate on SO.

Answer (score 4):

You could

1. put all elements in a into a hashtable -- O(n)
2. Factorize x -- O(sqrt(x))
3. Build all possible triplets of divisors of x -- O(3^log(x))
4. Search for these triplets in your Hashtable -- O(1)
5. If a triplet exists, increase your counter -- O(1)

The runtime will now be dependent on the number of prime factors pf(x) of x, specifically O(3^pf(x)). Since the number of prime factors of x can be bounded by log(x) this yields **O(3^log(x))** which could actually simplify further dependent on the exact base.

Comment: isn´t it pf(x)^3 ?

Comment: no, you do NOT want to choose 3 elements from pf(x) BUT you want to build 3 groups from pf(x) numbers. There are 3^n possibilities to build 3 groups from n elements.

Comment: @juvian Right, I'm mixing prime factors and divisors here. My bad.

Comment: Yeah I got confused too :)

Comment: @SaiBot, I would appreciate if you could add code snippet!

Comment: Sorry, not a big c++ programmer. Additionally,  StackOverflow should not be a coding service. Try yourself and if you encounter problems, people will help.

Comment: @everclear prime factorization is in NP w.r.t. the input length (e.g., the number of bits of x) but can be performed in O(sqrt x) e.g., with [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). [Check this post for more details](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624390/why-isnt-integer-factorization-in-complexity-p-when-you-can-factorize-n-in-o%E2%88%9A)

Answer (score 0):

Code is in java but as you know, the idea remains the same.

Time complexity is `O(n^1.5)`. I checked this with 10^5 elements and it works ok. 
The idea is-

- Put all elements of the list with their count in a map.
- Now, if `a[i]*a[j]*a[k] == x` to be `true`, all these 3 have to be factors of `x`. Hence, if `x%a[i] == 0`, I hunt for checking all factors(pairs) that multiply to `x/a[i]` in `sqrt(x/a[i])` time.
- Since, we do it for every element in the list, complexity goes like this-

  - O(n) for adding elements to map.
  - O(n * n^0.5) for checking triplets.

So, total complexity = O(n) +  O(n * n^0.5) = O(n^1.5) asymptotically.

**ASSUMPTION** - I am considering tuples as triplets having different indices in the array.

**UPDATE** - Current code considers different permutations of the same indices `i,j,k` as different tuples. You can fix it by having an additional map storing triplet indices as a string by joining them `|` (pipe) separated.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class Solution{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        String[] s = br.readLine().split("\\s");
        int[] a = new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
            a[i] = Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
        }
        int x = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println(solve(a,n,x));
    }

    private static long solve(int a[], int n, int x) {
        long tuples = 0;
        Map<Integer,Integer> elements = new HashMap<>();

        for(int i=0;i<a.length;++i){
            elements.put(a[i],elements.getOrDefault(a[i],0) + 1);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<a.length;++i){
            if(x%a[i] == 0){
                tuples += factorPairs(x/a[i],elements,a[i]);
            }
        }

        return tuples;
    }

    private static long factorPairs(int x,Map<Integer,Integer> elements,int factor1){
        long pairs = 0;
        for(int i=1;i*i<=x;++i){
            int second = i;
            int third = x/i;
            if(second*third == x && elements.containsKey(second) && elements.containsKey(third)){
                long second_cnt = elements.get(second) - (second == factor1 ? 1 : 0);
                long third_cnt = elements.get(third) - (third == factor1 ? 1 : 0);
                pairs += second_cnt * third_cnt;
            }
        }

        return pairs;   
    }
}
```